# Looking for open source testing tool that can be used to test Flash based applications

Tags: automated-testing, flash

I am looking for a open source testing tool that can be used to test Flash based applications.  I Googled and found "AutoTest Flash" but it seems to be in a dormant state.  Has anybody used that tool or another similar tool?

Comment: Also see https://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use and http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php

Answer (score 6):

There are a few options, and which tool works for you depends on your specific circumstance, so heres a list of the ones I've seen used;

- [FlexMonkey](http://flexmonkey.gorillalogic.com/) - Provides an IDE recorder, test case exporting and can be integrated into CI tools such as Jenkins using its ANT tasks.

  - Pros: Creates FlexUnit test cases
  - Cons: Doesn't play well with custom components or very complex interfaces
- [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) - Doesn't test Flash as such, but uses Image Recognition tech to recognise buttons/layout elements etc, and can control *any* application

  - Pros: Can interact on *anything* the user can see
  - Cons: Struggles with highly variable interfaces (dynamic backdrops, etc) and doesn't allow you to validate text very easily (ie you can't do things like; assertThat(page.getTitle(), is(equalTo("Some Expected Title")));
- [flash-selenium](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/) - An extension to the very popular Selenium test system

  - Pros : Lets you maintain a common work flow if you're using Flash within other html content
  - Cons : Requires building a Selenium version of the flash application

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Sikuli. it is easy to use and you are not limited by the underlying technology of the application. Can be used to test on almost any os/device if you have access to the UI(any kind of vnc or rdc)