# Open-source functional testing automation tools for testing Silverlight based applications

Tags: automated-testing, functional, open-source, flash, silverlight

I am looking for an open-source functional testing automation tool that supports testing of Silverlight based applications.

To be more specific, the tool should be able to recognize objects within the Silverlight applications.

I have found a question that talks about [testing Adobe Flash (or Flex) based applications](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5065/looking-for-open-source-testing-tool-that-can-be-used-to-test-flash-based-applic), but I would like to ask for help in dealing with similar testing automation experience on Microsoft Silverlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [White APIs](http://white.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Basically, you are suggesting to use the same VS create my tests. My only concern here is that this testing process have some similarities for white-box or maybe unit-testing for the Silverlight apps. I would appreciate if you can provide additional options to facilitate something like black-box testing. Also, I wonder if that is supported by VS Test Manager itself.

Comment: White is an automation framework that can be used to design and develop tests for rich clients (GUI automation).

Answer (score 1):

Selenium also has support for Silverlight apps. Please check post - Silvernium ~ Selenium for [Silverlight Applications.](http://assertselenium.com/2012/11/07/silvernium-selenium-for-silverlight-applications/)