# Silverlight web application automation tools?

Tags: uiautomation, silverlight

I am looking to automate our regression test cases for a silverlight application we have and was wondering if anyone has done this and could suggest tools that can be used to do this quickly.

Comment: Check here you will get possible answers from above question.

Answer (score 0):

Two newer tools not mentioned in the [old answer (2012)](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5083/open-source-functional-testing-automation-tools-for-testing-silverlight-based-ap) are:

- [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) (actually a desktop automation software, but also usable for [web testing](http://www.sikuli.org/testing.html), cross-platform)
- [Kantu](https://a9t9.com/) supports [Flash/Silverlight testing](https://a9t9.com/kantu/flash) (image-driven web automation wrapper for Google Chrome, Windows only)