# Telerik vs TestComplete for Silverlight web application automation

Tags: automated-testing, testcomplete, telerik, silverlight

I am looking to automate regression testing of our web application software. Has anyone used Telerik or TestComplete before for testing Silverlight applications, and if you have, can you share your experiences and share which of these tools would be best suited for automated testing of a Silverlight web application?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the tools mentioned in the answers to https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5083/open-source-functional-testing-automation-tools-for-testing-silverlight-based-ap?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find much "Getting started" material for Silvernium, if you know any tutorials to get started let me know. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

I used Telerik for some testing purpose. it is a good tool and it gives a lot of features like Cross-browser support and performance testing support but Telerik only supports Windows environment.

Actually, I didn't work with TestComplete but when I search about your question I found TestComplete is more suitable for the systems that have more interfaces.